# Localhost is not displaying incoming https

Tags: apache, mamp, adsapi-php.ini

I am using MAMP as my local host and PHP 7.3.8 as my localhost.

On my site I am trying to connect to google maps as follows:

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$postcode1&destinations=$postcode2&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false&key=MY-API-KEY"
$data = @file_get_content($url)
```

However for some reason the connection is not established
when I try this on a live site (using GoDaddy as a server) all is well and I get the wanted result.

I have tried to switch on `allow_url_fopen`in the php.ini and have checked the firewall on my localhost and made sure the ports are open, however no joy.

Anyhelp to solve this problem welcome

Comment: It might be because it is not hosted on the domain.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana Thank you for your reply, however the localhost is on my computer this is where I would like to test it however for some reason it will not return the $data contents

Comment: Maybe the google api doesn't allow you to use it in the host: localhost. Maybe turn on display_errors by adding ```ini_set("display_errors", "1");``` to the top of your document.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana thank you for your reply however I have already done that and it just won't load the page not he localhost no errors are reported

Comment: Now, I think it is a problem with PHP.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana thank you again, would you know what the problem with php might be this is way I changed the allow_url_fopen.

Comment: Does a basic PHP script work? And also try creating a info.php file and just typing in: ```<?php phpinfo(); ```. Also, do you have the required php packages installed? You can compare them to your server by using the phpinfo() function (but, do it in a private page)

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana all the normal this work I have tried to replace the link with http://bbc.co.uk and that seems to work fine, it seems like it doesn't like the parameters behind it like the &orgins etc any idea what might be that?

Comment: I think google is the one which is not allowing you to use the api

Comment: Did you replace MY-API-KEY to your api

Comment: My API is replaced with the one google gave me, I just didn't want to share that one online so anyone could use it

Comment: Thats good, also I am going to move this to the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205747/discussion-between-chi-c-j-rajeeva-lochana-and-ria).